# Angular async function call from template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, async-await, observable

I try to build an image-cache service for my Ionic application.

```
<ion-col [routerLink]="['/category-detail',cat.objectId,i]" class="category-item"
      *ngFor="let cat of categories;index as i" size="3">
      <ion-img class="cat-image" [src]="getImage(cat.image.url) | async">
      </ion-img>
      <p class="cat-name">
        {{cat.name}}
      </p>
    </ion-col>
```

I am calling the function from src tag in ion-image

```
async getImage(fileUrl: any) {
    return await this.cacheService.checkFile(fileUrl);
  }
```

This functions checking a file if its there it returns URL of file else it returns URL in parameter

```
public async checkFile(fileUrl) {
    let stringURL = String(fileUrl);
    let fileName = stringURL.split('//')[1].replace(/\//g, '-');
    return this.file.checkFile(this.file.tempDirectory, fileName)
      .then(
        async result => {
          if (result) {
            return this.file.tempDirectory + fileName;
          } else {
            return fileUrl;
          }
        }
      )
      .catch(
        async err => {
          //FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR
          if (err.code == 1) {
            let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
            return fileTransfer.download(fileUrl, this.file.tempDirectory + fileName, true)
              .then(
                result => {
                  console.log(result);
                  return result;
                }
              )
              .catch(
                error => {
                  throw error;
                }
              )

          } else {
            throw err;
          }

        }
      )
  }
```

I searched various of questions and examples but none of them worked for me.

My goal is try to return a dynamic URL with a promise chain.

I am so confused with async,promise and observable keywords in Angular.

My project config :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.9.1 (/Users/suatkarabacak/npm/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.14.0
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.3 Build version 11C29
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a custom pipe in this case to implement your requirement.

so basically you have something like the following in your template:

```
<ion-col ... *ngFor="let cat of categories ..." ...>
   <ion-img ... [src]="cat | catImageUrl | async"></ion-img>
</ion-col>
```

Then you'll implement a custom [Angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) getting cat image URL from a cat object asynchronously:

```
@Pipe({name: 'catImageUrl'})
export class CatImageUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(/* inject your cache service */) {}

  transform(cat: Category): Promise<string> {
    return this.cacheService.checkFile(cat.image.url);
  }
}
```

And that's all you need. Basically you compose 2 pipes together to make a `Category -> Promise<string> -> string` transformation to get the image url.

Comment: Thanks that was I looking foor !

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your `checkFile` method, but you can use the `async` pipe:

```
image : Promise<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.cat) {
    this.image = this.cacheService.checkFile(this.cat.image.url);
  }
}
```

```
<ion-img class="cat-image" [src]="image | async"></ion-img>
```

basically, you only need to use `async/await` if you really want to wait for a Promise. When you are actually returning the promise, there is no use of it. Just clutters your code

Comment: I just change the code exactly like in your response and added a simple promise response instead of checkFile method but it becomes recursive and browser does not respond. What am I missing ?

Comment: How should I pass fileUrl parameter in declaration ?

Comment: I don't know where your `cat` is defined. I've updated my answer to give you some options

Comment: It is my bad to not mention about *ngFor I edited my question. Function parameter is a dynamic variable.

Comment: the answer is still more or less the same, but you're going to run a `map` or `forEach` on `categories` and set that `image` property on all of the items in the array the same way. you can't do this the way you're trying to do it with an async function call from template. it doesn't work.